# Remove Span's White Spaces Completly (Squish it) at Top and Bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let say I have,

```
<span class="labels" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #000000;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 11px; ">74.58 ft.</span>
```

I need to squish the span as much as possible. So that it will only show text. Any trick, javascript, jquery, css is acceptable.

http://jsfiddle.net/QgGpy/

Comment: You want to have the text without css or what?

Comment: @Justin solved my problem. See below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` and set a `line-height` to control the height.

http://jsfiddle.net/QgGpy/12/

Note that you'll miss the descenders (e.g. "y" or "j") if you shrink line height below the font size, but if you know the text in advance and know it has no descenders, then you'll be OK.

```
<span class="labels"

 style="font-size: 11px; line-height:9px; display:inline-block; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000;font-family: Verdana;"

>74.58 ft.</span>
```

Comment: Genious. It's the line height that solve my problem. What do you mean by 'missing the descenders Y or j'

Comment: Some letters like y, j, g, and p are "descenders" meaning they have pixels below the line that most other letters end. If you have 11px text with descenders and you use 9px line height, you'll overflow. Similarly, some letters are very tall (e.g. lowercase l). So always need to be careful when setting a line height smaller than your font size. If you know the text in advance (no descenders, no tall letters) then you can use a smaller line-height, but not if the text is unknown. See http://jsfiddle.net/QgGpy/14/ for more details.

Comment: Yes, I know the text is always some digits with ft, mt. So this is not a problem for me. Thanks again.